Permissible least bounds of uniformly bounded matrices
Let $A$ be an invertible matrix such that we have $|x| \leq B$ for every element $x$ in $A^i$, $i > 0$. Apparently this is called uniform boundedness of a matrix. If $A$ is integer coefficient, then a result is that $A^n = I$ for some $n$, which is not to confused with the dimension of $A$.
For all real uniformly bounded matrices, we quickly get from Hadamard's inequality that $\mathrm{|\det(A)|} \leq 1$. Moving on we see that all least bounds are permissible for $B$, because $A$ can be an involutory matrix, that is, $A^2 = I$. For example, $2 \times 2$ matrices with the form of
$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d
 \end{pmatrix}$
are involutory if $a^2+bc = 1$. Then by choosing large $a$ we are choosing a large least bound $B$.
However, if we force $n > 2$ (or $i$ depending on your preference), I could not find available literature on the subject. My experiments so far seem to indicate that for $n$ large enough, the least bound necessarily tends to $1$, so if $A$ is integer coefficient then $n$ and the largest bound $B$ are inversely proportional, or if $A$ is real (transcendental) we are going to have $B \leq 1$.
For example, we know that complex numbers are isomorphic to a certain type of $2 \times 2$ matrix, we can then have a transcendental imaginary number $z$ with $|z| = 1$, which is bounded for all $i$. For $3 \times 3$ integer-coefficient matrices I know an example that is least bound by $B=3$, it also happens for this example that we have $n=3$. Also we can have that $A^i$ tends to the zero-matrix, so we can have a least bound $B < 1$.
Question: if $A$ is uniformly bounded and $A^i \neq I$ for all $i > 0$, does it follow that the least bound is $B\leq1$?
